# add a date to a new cell whenever the % of one cell updates to 100% and keep that date static once it has been updated

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a date to a new cell whenever the % of one cell updates to 100% and keep that date static once it has been updated.

So, I tried using the `=TODAY()` function in a table in excel. However, once data has been entered into that table cell, I would like it to never change dates again, effectively capturing the date the row's data became 100%.

The row that updates, updates from another sheet in the workbook when I hit refresh on that particular worksheet. It is possible that when a cell updates to 100%, it will update again to 100% whenever I refresh.

How can I keep the date static the first time that cell updates to 100%?   This will be used on every row in the date column, so as data is entered into the table down the rows, each date will be captured.

Is this possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the date and time stamp as static. It assumes the % are in column H and the date is one column to the right. Put the code in your worksheet code section. This works for manual % cell changes.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$H:$H")) Is Nothing And Target.Value = 1 And Target.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now()
End If
End Sub
```

Try this for updates to a cell based on dependencies. Also caters for you blanking the date field if you go below 100%. This looks for changes in the cells that your percent cell is dependent on. I've only tested it on the same sheet for simplicity but would expect it to work across sheets.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myDependencies As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set myDependencies = Range(Target.Dependents.Address)
On Error GoTo exitsub
If Not Intersect(myDependencies, Range("$H:$H")) Is Nothing Then
    If myDependencies.Value = 1 And myDependencies.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
        myDependencies.Offset(0, 1) = Now()
    Else
        If myDependencies.Value < 1 Then
            myDependencies.Offset(0, 1) = ""
        End If
    End If
End If
exitsub:
End Sub
```

Amendment to meet your requirement of the dependencies being on a different sheet.
Code uses Sheet5 as the active sheet. Contains values that change and drive % change. %s are on Sheet2.

There are other ways to do this and a loop may be slow but you said you can't identify specific individual change as all cells are refreshed. So this code checks all the % values in Sheet2 every time anything on Sheet5 changes.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet
Dim pctRange As Range
Dim pctCell As Range

Set Sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set pctRange = Sh2.Range("A2:A4") ' set range to the range that contains your percents on Sheet2
'
For Each pctCell In pctRange
' next test should be =100 or =1 depending on how your percent cells are formatted 
    If pctCell.Value = 100 Then
        If pctCell.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
            pctCell.Offset(0, 1) = Now()
        End If
    Else
        pctCell.Offset(0, 1) = ""
    End If
Next pctCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Question: How can I run both your amendment on sheet5 and also run the msgbox code to tell me that it was triggered? When i try to have the Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range) Msgbox "triggered" end sub along with our ammendment, it tells me that ambiguous name detected. How do I get around that?

Comment: You can only have one worksheet_change sub in each sheet so with that info you can probably work it out?

Comment: Great :) If you can upvote or mark this as the answer to your question I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.